# For Sql performances, several equals or one between

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

For a new developement, I will have a big SQL table (~100M rows).
4 fields will be used to query the data.

Is it better to query one concatenated field with between or several equals ?

Exemple :

MainTable

```
PkId | Label | FkId1 | FkId2 | FkId3 | FkId4
1    | test  | 1     | 4     | 3     | 1
```

Datas in Fk tables are static, example :

FkTable1

```
Id | Value
1  | a
2  | b
3  | c
```

To query the datas, the classic sql query is :

```
select Label, FkId1, FkId2, FkId3, FkId4 
from MainTable
where FkId1=1 and FkId2=2 and FkId3 in(2, 3)
```

The idea to optimize performance is to add one field "UniqueId" calculated backend before the insert :

```
UniqueId = FkId1*1000000 + FkId2*10000 + FkId3*100 + FkId4
```

```
PkId | Label | FkId1 | FkId2 | FkId3 | FkId4 | UniqueId
1    | test  | 1     | 4     | 3     | 1     | 1040301
```

```
select Label, FkId1, FkId2, FkId3, FkId4 
from MainTable
where UniqueId between 1020200 and 1040000
```

Moreover, with the UniqueId field, an index on this field only will be sufficient.

What do you think ?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when your value for FkId3 is 100? Your logic will no longer work. Do NOT fall into the trap of premature optimization. You are on the verge of making non-standard design decisions to fix a performance issue that has not yet occurred. There is nothing wrong with a 4 column key like this. Use proper table structure and deal with performance problems when they happen.

Comment: Similarly, think through what happens when you need FkId1 in (2,3)...

Comment: @Sean Lange : it's not premature optimization, we will setup the new system with current system datas

Comment: @Philip Kelley : you're right

Comment: Actually your question is a textbook definition of premature optimization. You stated this is new development and you are asking if you should use a very non-standard column to make queries faster. Call what you want, you are considering a non-standard approach to handle a performance issue that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this query:

```
select Label, FkId1, FkId2, FkId3, FkId4 
from MainTable
where FkId1 = 1 and FkId2 = 2 and FkId3 in (2, 3)
```

The optimal index is on `MainTable(FkID1, FkId2, FkId3)`.  You can also add `Label` and `FkId4` to the index if you want a covering index (so the index can handle the entire query without referring to the original data pages).

There is no need for a computed field for the example you provided.

Comment: thank's a lot everyone, I will not add a computed field

Answer (score 0):

Since you will have 100M rows, thinking about optimisations from the start seems sensible to me.
However, your proposed solution will not work in this way:

1. Your formula above has two times the SAME factor 10000. You have to use   different factors, i.e. different powers of 10.
2. Your select example has a "IN" clause (FkId3 in(2, 3)). This will only work, if only one of the FKs is queried this way. This fk should be the one with no factor in the formula for computing UniqueId (i.e. gives the least significant Digits of UniqueId).

Now seeing Gordons answer, I agree with him, i.e. using a combined index may be good enough for you (though your solution would probably slightly better). However, also the combined index has a similar problem: The FK field beeing queried with the IN clause should be the last field in the index.